# Android Recyclerview fail getting data from database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, handler

```
class ResultRecycleViewAdapter(val mDatabase : PromiseDatabase, val request:Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultRecycleViewAdapter.ResultViewHolder>() {
    var yesList: List<Promise> = ArrayList<Promise>()
    val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    var noList: List<Promise> = ArrayList<Promise>()
    var mHandler = android.os.Handler()
    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        setYesList()
        setNoList()
        Log.d("RecyclerView", "onAttachedToRecyclerView() 실행")
    }
    fun setYesList() {
        Log.d("RecyclerView", "setYesList() 실행")
        executor.execute(Runnable {
            val tmp = mDatabase.promiseDao().getSuccessPromise()
            Log.d("RecyclerView", ""+tmp )
            mHandler.post(
                Runnable {

                    yesList=  tmp
                    Log.d("RecyclerView", "mHandler.Post()"+this.yesList+" "+yesList)
                }
            )
        })
    }

    fun setNoList() {
        Log.d("RecyclerView", "setNoList() 실행")
        executor.execute(Runnable {
            val tmp = mDatabase.promiseDao().getFailPromise()
            Log.d("RecyclerView", ""+tmp)
            mHandler.post(
                Runnable {
                    Log.d("RecyclerView", "mHandler.Post()")
                    noList = tmp
                }
            )
        })
    }

    inner class ResultViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        (LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.result_recyclerview, parent, false)) {
        val content = parent.findViewById(R.id.content_textView_recyclerView) as TextView
        val date = parent.findViewById(R.id.date_textView_recyclerView) as TextView


    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ResultViewHolder {
        Log.d("RecyclerView", "onCreateViewHolder() 실행")
        val v =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.result_recyclerview, parent, false)
        return ResultViewHolder(v as ViewGroup)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("RecyclerView", "getItemCount() 실행 noListSize : "+noList.size+" yesListSize : "+yesList.size)
    if(request == 0) return noList.size else  return yesList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ResultViewHolder, position: Int) {

        Log.d("RecyclerView", "onBindViewHolder() 실행")
        Log.d("RecyclerView", yesList.toString() +" "+noList.toString())
        if(request == 0){//noList
            for(item in noList){
                holder.content.text = item.content
                holder.date.text = unixTimeToDate(item.date)
            }
        }
        else if(request == 1){
            for(item in yesList){
                holder.content.text = item.content
                holder.date.text = unixTimeToDate(item.date)
            }
        }
    }
    fun unixTimeToDate(currentTimeMillis : Int) : String{
        Log.d("RecyclerView", "unixTimeToDate() 실행")
        val simpleDataFormat : SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy년 MM월 dd일  HH시 mm분 ss초")
        return simpleDataFormat.format(currentTimeMillis)
    }


}
```

executor is for access to room. mHandler for send mainThread the list data.
I expected that the yesList and noList have items. but unfortunately they don't.
the getItemCount() function just returns 0.

but the executor and handler do their job well. and the local varable tmp has exact value. but it doesn't work to assign tmp value to local member variable yesList or noList.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call **notifyDatasetChanged()** in your adapter.

```
mHandler.post(
      Runnable {

         yesList=  tmp
          notifyDataSetChanged() // Should call this to notify adapter
       }
 )
```

Everytime you set, add, or update your list, your adapter doesn't know this yet unless you call adapter notifyDataSetChanged for ex. By notifying your adapter it does then call it's overide methods (e.g getItemCount()) and thus refreshing the list.

Comment: where should I call the method??

Comment: oh thank you. It works. But can you explain why it happens? And why should called in handler.post?